Issue with installing vscode extensions through devcontainer.json #174
I am having an issue with devcontainer. I have a devcontainer.json file and its not installing the vscode extensions. I am using a custom Dockerfile
Note: Running devcontainer inside a coder workspace deployed on a kubernetes cluster.
Need help on this
I need to install extensions listed in devcontainer.json file
{
        "name": "App: Node, PostgreSQL, Redis, Nginx (coder.com)",
        "build": {
                "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
                "args": {
                        "GIT_USERNAME": "${localEnv:GIT_USERNAME}",
                        "CODER_DOMAIN_SUFFIX": "${localEnv:CODER_DOMAIN_SUFFIX}"
                }
        },
       
    // This can be used to network with other containers or with the host.
    "forwardPorts": ["3841"],
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
            "settings": {},
            // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.

            // copied from .vscode/extensions.json
            "extensions": [
                // "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker", most devs won't need this?
                "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
                "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
                "bradymholt.pgformatter", // format sql files
                "hediet.hediet-i18n-helper", // auto-generates translation ids and converts text to <Trans /> components
                // "eamodio.gitlens", optional, useful, but a bit annoying with trial versions and premium reminders etc
                "styled-components.vscode-styled-components"
                // "wix.vscode-import-cost", useful but eats a ton of resources
            ]
        }
    },

    // Use 'postStartCommand' to run commands after the container has started.
    // "postStartCommand": "yarn install && yarn run dev-container",

    // Comment out to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
    //"remoteUser": "node",
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/git:1": {
            "version": "os-provided"
        }
    }
}```

